# Unable to store Vector data when calling "call" method in Java

Tags: java, vector, threadpool, runnable

I have a problem with my code. Code is about to find gateways/subnets and if program finds one it returns it to a class that called "call()" method. That part works fine but problem is that I want to pass ID of gateway(you know if gateway was 192.168.1.**1** , it will also pass number **1** to class that fills vector of founded gateways). Problem is that for some reason vector that holds IDs of gateways is empty. Can you give me a clue how to fix problem ? Best regards. 
Here is code that I used in my project:

```
int GateWayKey = 1;
int GateWayKeyStop=254;
String ip="";
StoredGW FoundedGW = new StoredGW();
int SubNetKey = 2;
int SubNetKeyStop = 254;
Vector <Integer> AllGateWays= new Vector <Integer>();
Vector <Future<String>> AllSQLs = new Vector <Future<String>>();

final int NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
public void run() {


    for (;GateWayKey<=GateWayKeyStop;GateWayKey++){
        ip="192.168."+GateWayKey+".1";
        AllSQLs.add(exec.submit((new PingTask(ip,GateWayKey))));
    }
        AllGateWays = FoundedGW.GiveMeGWs();
    for (int j : AllGateWays){
        for (;SubNetKey<=SubNetKeyStop;SubNetKey++){
            ip="192.168."+j+"."+SubNetKey;         
            AllSQLs.add (exec.submit(new PingTask(ip,null))));
        }
 exec.shutdown();
}
```

Here is class that preform pinging and storing ID of gateway:

```
public class PingTask implements Callable <String> {
String ips; 
int GateWay;
public PingTask (){
}

public PingTask (String ip, int GateWayKey){
    ips=ip;
    GateWay=GateWayKey;
}

public String call(){
    InetAddress address;
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByName(ips);
        try {
            if (address.isReachable(5000)) { 
                        StoredGW GWs = new StoredGW();
                        GWs.addNewGW(GateWay);
                } else {
                        return null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return null;
        }
}
}
```

and here is class where I store GateWays

```
public class StoredGW {
Vector <Integer> AllFoundedGWs= new Vector<Integer>();
public void addNewGW(int i){
    AllFoundedGWs.add(i);
}
public Vector<Integer> GiveMeGWs(){
    return AllFoundedGWs;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
StoredGW GWs = new StoredGW();
GWs.addNewGW(GateWay);
```

You make a new StoreGW (as local variable) and then you throw it away. Instead use, `FoundedGW`. You have to make sure it is visible to your task, you might have to pass it as a constructor argument so that it can be used within your task.

Try this:

```
public class PingTask implements Callable <String> {
    String ips; 
    int GateWay;
    StoredGW store;

    public PingTask (){
    }

    public PingTask (String ip, int GateWayKey, StoredGW store){
        ips=ip;
        GateWay=GateWayKey;
                    this.store = store;
    }

    public String call(){
        InetAddress address;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName(ips);
            try {
                if (address.isReachable(5000)) { 
                            store.addNewGW(GateWay);
                    } else {
                            return null;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it this way:

```
AllSQLs.add(exec.submit((new PingTask(ip,GateWayKey, FoundedGW))));
```

As an unrelated side note, you need to take a look at the [standard for Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it'll make your code easier for others to understand.

Comment: +1 for the conventions :) And I'd like to add that Vector is synchronized. If you do not need that, use Lists.